# Как сделать цикл слайдеру?

Tags: javascript, циклы, slider

Есть код, но когда слайдер подходит к последнему изображению, он начинает идти в обнатном порядке, а не сначала. Не знаю как правильно сделать

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var curPage = 1;
  var numOfPages = $(".skw-page").length;
  var animTime = 1000;
  var scrolling = false;
  var pgPrefix = ".skw-page-";

  //Start slide auto control
  var flag = false;
  var tick;
  var slideTime = 2000;
  var but = document.getElementById('start');
  but.addEventListener('click', startStop);
  function startStop () {
    but.innerHTML = but.innerHTML == 'Stop' ? 'Start' : 'Stop'; 
    if(tick) {
       clearInterval(tick);
       tick = false;
     }else{
       tick = setInterval(()=>{
         if(curPage === numOfPages) flag = true;
         if(curPage === 1) flag = false;
         flag ? navigateUp() : navigateDown();
       },slideTime)
     }
  }
    setTimeout(startStop, 1000);
  //End slide auto control


  function pagination() {
    scrolling = true;

    $(pgPrefix + curPage).removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");
    $(pgPrefix + (curPage - 1)).addClass("inactive");
    $(pgPrefix + (curPage + 1)).removeClass("active");

    setTimeout(function() {
      scrolling = false;
    }, animTime);
  };

  function navigateUp() {
    if (curPage === 1) return;
    curPage--;
    pagination();
  };

  function navigateDown() {
    if (curPage === numOfPages) return;
    curPage++;
    pagination();
  };


  $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (scrolling) return;
    if (e.which === 38) {
      navigateUp();
    } else if (e.which === 40) {
      navigateDown();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #15181A;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#start{
  margin: 0 auto;
  height:20px;
  width:50px;
  background: #E1ECF4;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#start:hover{
background: #E1ECC1;
}
.skw-pages {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.skw-page {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.skw-page__half {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.skw-page__half--left {
  left: 0;
  transform: translate3d(-32.4vh, 100%, 0);
}
.skw-page__half--right {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(32.4vh, -100%, 0);
}
.skw-page.active .skw-page__half {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.skw-page__skewed {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 140%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: skewX(-18deg);
  background: #000;
}
.skw-page__half--left .skw-page__skewed {
  left: -40%;
}
.skw-page__half--right .skw-page__skewed {
  right: -40%;
}
.skw-page__content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 30%;
  color: #fff;
  transform: skewX(18deg);
  transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s;
  background-size: cover;
}
.skw-page__half--left .skw-page__content {
  padding-left: 30%;
  padding-right: 30%;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}
.skw-page__half--right .skw-page__content {
  padding-left: 30%;
  padding-right: 30%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
.skw-page.inactive .skw-page__content {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: skewX(18deg) scale(0.95);
}
.skw-page__heading {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
.skw-page__description {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Skewed One Page Scroll</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->

<div class="skw-pages">
  <div class="skw-page skw-page-1 active">
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--left">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--right">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content">
          <h2 class="skw-page__heading"></h2>
          <p class="skw-page__description">Just dunc now</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="start"></div>
  <div class="skw-page skw-page-2">
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--left">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content">
          <h2 class="skw-page__heading">Page 2</h2>
          <p class="skw-page__description">Nothing to do here, continue scrolling.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--right">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="skw-page skw-page-3">
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--left">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--right">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content">
          <h2 class="skw-page__heading">Page 3</h2>
          <p class="skw-page__description">The end is near, I promise!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="skw-page skw-page-4">
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--left">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content">
          <h2 class="skw-page__heading">Page 4</h2>
          <p class="skw-page__description">Ok, ok, just one more scroll!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--right">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="skw-page skw-page-5">
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--left">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--right">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content">
          <h2 class="skw-page__heading">Epic finale</h2>
          <p class="skw-page__description">
            Feel free to check 
            <a class="skw-page__link" href="https://codepen.io/suez/pens/public/" target="_blank">my other pens</a> and follow me on 
            <a class="skw-page__link" href="https://twitter.com/NikolayTalanov" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
Развернуть фрагмент
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теперь идёт сначала..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var curPage = 1;
  var numOfPages = $(".skw-page").length;
  var animTime = 1000;
  var pgPrefix = ".skw-page-";

  //Start slide auto control
  var tick;  
  function startStop (f) { 
    if(f) clearInterval(tick);
    tick = setInterval(()=>{
      if(curPage === numOfPages) revers();
      navigateUp();
    },2000)     
  }  
  function revers(){
    for(var i = 1; i<numOfPages+1; i++){
     $(pgPrefix + i).removeClass("active inactive");
    }
    curPage = curPage == 1 ? numOfPages : 0;
    $(pgPrefix + curPage).addClass("active");
  }
  setTimeout(startStop, 1000);
  //End slide auto control


  function pagination() {    
    $(pgPrefix + curPage).
    removeClass("inactive").addClass("active")    
    $(pgPrefix + (curPage - 1)).addClass("inactive");
    $(pgPrefix + (curPage + 1)).removeClass("active");    
  };

  function navigateDown() {
    if (curPage === 1) return revers()
    curPage--;
    pagination();
  };
  function navigateUp() {
  if(curPage === numOfPages) return revers()
    curPage++;
    pagination();
  };
  $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    startStop('update');
    if (e.which === 38) navigateUp();
    if (e.which === 40) navigateDown();
  });

});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #15181A;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#start{
  margin: 0 auto;
  height:20px;
  width:50px;
  background: #E1ECF4;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#start:hover{
background: #E1ECC1;
}
.skw-pages {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.skw-page {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.skw-page__half {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.skw-page__half--left {
  left: 0;
  transform: translate3d(-32.4vh, 100%, 0);
}
.skw-page__half--right {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(32.4vh, -100%, 0);
}
.skw-page.active .skw-page__half {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.skw-page__skewed {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 140%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: skewX(-18deg);
  background: #000;
}
.skw-page__half--left .skw-page__skewed {
  left: -40%;
}
.skw-page__half--right .skw-page__skewed {
  right: -40%;
}
.skw-page__content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 30%;
  color: #fff;
  transform: skewX(18deg);
  transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s;
  background-size: cover;
}
.skw-page__half--left .skw-page__content {
  padding-left: 30%;
  padding-right: 30%;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}
.skw-page__half--right .skw-page__content {
  padding-left: 30%;
  padding-right: 30%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
.skw-page.inactive .skw-page__content {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: skewX(18deg) scale(0.95);
}
.skw-page__heading {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
.skw-page__description {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Skewed One Page Scroll</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->

<div class="skw-pages">
  <div class="skw-page skw-page-1 active">
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--left">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--right">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content">
          <h2 class="skw-page__heading"></h2>
          <p class="skw-page__description">Just dunc now</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="start"></div>
  <div class="skw-page skw-page-2">
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--left">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content">
          <h2 class="skw-page__heading">Page 2</h2>
          <p class="skw-page__description">Nothing to do here, continue scrolling.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--right">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="skw-page skw-page-3">
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--left">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--right">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content">
          <h2 class="skw-page__heading">Page 3</h2>
          <p class="skw-page__description">The end is near, I promise!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="skw-page skw-page-4">
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--left">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content">
          <h2 class="skw-page__heading">Page 4</h2>
          <p class="skw-page__description">Ok, ok, just one more scroll!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--right">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="skw-page skw-page-5">
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--left">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--right">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content">
          <h2 class="skw-page__heading">Epic finale</h2>
          <p class="skw-page__description">
            Feel free to check 
            <a class="skw-page__link" href="https://codepen.io/suez/pens/public/" target="_blank">my other pens</a> and follow me on 
            <a class="skw-page__link" href="https://twitter.com/NikolayTalanov" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
Развернуть фрагмент
```